# JDBC connection works in IDE (eclipse), but not in .jar file

Tags: java, sql-server, eclipse, jdbc, jar

I'm really looking at a mystery here. I created a Java program in Eclipse and established a JDBC connection. The code is the following:

```
import java.sql.*;

public class Login {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            // Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
            Connection connection = DriverManager
                    .getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=testdb; integratedSecurity=true;");
                                   //adding port 1433 doesn't make a difference 

            System.out.println("Connection successful");
            Statement st = connection.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select * from testtable");

            while (rs.next()) {
                line = rs.getString(2);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

When I'm running it within eclipse, everything's fine. The database and tables are good, library and authentication in the **Java Built Path** are set and I get the result I want, namely "Hello World", which is a string in the selected table.

But creating an executable JAR file and running it throws the exception "**This driver is not configured for integrated authentication**". It does not even connect, so even if there was an error in the database it wouldn't matter at this point.

Even more confusing is the fact, that some weeks earlier, I also created an executable JAR file and it worked!

**OS**: Windows Vista Home Premium x86

**JDBC driver location**: "C:\sqljdbc_4.0\enu\sqljdbc4.jar"

**Native library location**: "C:\sqljdbc_4.0\enu\auth\x86"

**Java version**: Java 7 Update 17 and JDK 7 Update 17

Previousely, I used Update 21, but I changed back to check if the driver could be the reason.

So, any suggestions? I'd be very grateful!

Comment: did you set the system property "java.library.path" to the location of your sqljdbc_auth.dll?

Comment: *"I hope this is an SSCCE"* - will this allow other people to reproduce your problem?  If not, it is not an SSCCE.

Comment: How do you execute the jar?

Comment: Concerning **SSCCE**: If people copy paste the code, add something (i.e. a JFrame) so they can see the problem when the JAR file is created and executed, they should be able to see the problem.
If it doesn't voilate the simplicity, I could provide the code for that right away, so people really just need to copy-paste.
Concerning **sqljdbc_auth.dll**: In the added sqljdbc4.jar, I set the **native library location** to: _"C:/sqljdbc_4.0/enu/auth/x86"_ (which of course exists)

Comment: Lateral suggestion: do you have to use SQL server? For an assignment, an embedded database would work better

Comment: I only had the choice between Sybase, MySQL (by using PhpMyAdmin) and SQL Server 2012. I've decided for SQL Server, because Sybase is in my eyes crappy (no intellisense what so ever) and I would have had to go through some authorization process to get a MySQL server plus I never used it before, so chosing SQL Server used to be the most userfriendly alternative (in my eyes)
Btw, what do you mean by "embedded database"? Embedded in what? The JAR file?

Comment: Might it have to do with the fact my package is still `(default package)` or the fact I'm **not** using `Eclipse IDE for Java EE`?

Comment: By "embedded" I meant into your application's process, requiring no separate server, and usually no authentication

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Check the runtime classpath of eclipse, then try to create a system level "CLASSPATH" variable and add the same path. Once the variable is set, execute it in new command prompt or reload the environment variables
- Make sure your executable jar has the dependency in MANIFEST.MF for all the necessary jars (along with MainClass)
- Finally, It is always a practice in Java to make the first alphabet in Capital ("Login" instead of "login")

Comment: Ok, concerning "CLASSPATH", I don't really know what to do. I very often read "set CLASSPATH", but nobody explains how and where...
And, the above code should just be an SSCCE. Actually, I'm building a GUI, so I'd like to see the result NOT in a command line, but in the GUI.
And finally, I have no clue where to set the MANIFEST.MF...
So it seems, I've either missed important things, or I set some stuff without knowing what I did. Could you give me some hints for that, please?

Comment: You could do it using `set CLASSPATH` in the command prompt or set an environment (system) variable in Computer->Properties->Advanced System Settings->Environment Variables

Comment: Is it possible to set the classpath as a Non-admin? Because this could be very important, since this program needs to run on a computer in my university.

Comment: **Do not set a systemwide classpath.** This is a terrible practice precisely because it's a deployment headache. Either use a launcher script that correctly calls `java -cp <the classpath> <everything else>`, or in an executable file, use a `MANIFEST.MF` file with a `Class-Path:` header, or bundle all the needed classes into the JAR using the Maven [shade plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/), or [JarJarLinks](https://code.google.com/p/jarjar/)

Comment: Also, there's probably a ton of results on the web and SO for "class-path manifest.mf" that tell you what needs to be placed where.

Comment: And seeing how the OP's error message isn't a `ClassDefNotFoundError`, it's probably not a classpath issue.

Comment: Yeah, well as I wrote already - Everything's working fine when I run the project from withing eclipse. I can do select, update, insert, delete - everything fine. But creating and running a JAR file it gives me the mentioned message. Plus, creating the JAR with a sub-folder containing the ref. classes only puts the `sqljdbc4.jar` into that folder. No `manifest.fm` or anything else...

Comment: @Stacky "Everything runs fine from within Eclipse" pretty much means you've failed to reproduce the environment Eclipse automagically sets up for you when you're launching the JAR manually. This environment includes the classpath, which can be set in an executable JAR's `MANIFEST.MF`, so go read the documentation about that file and what it does and where it should be and doublecheck whether all is as it should.

Comment: @Stacky: There's also the "library load path" for DLLs, happymeal already told you it's a system property, it can either be set as a command line parameter to `java`, maybe in the manifest as well, I'm not sure. Once again, read the docs. Actually *understanding* what Eclipse does when launching your program and how to do it manually is pretty important.

Comment: RTFM - I hear you! ;-)
I'm gonna do that and I really appreciate your patience!

Comment: @Stacky Right, finally on a normal computer. Anyway, this is the [technical note on setting the classpath](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html), and [the tutorial trail on JAR manifests](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/manifestindex.html). Can't find an authoritative source on the library load path (which I believe is the actual cause of your problem), but it should be sufficient to set the operating system's `PATH` environment variable, and for native libraries provided by separately installed servers it's the better practice.

Answer (score 0):

Actual problem is that if you run your project from eclipse, it will automatically add run arguments that are defined in run/run config//arguments, so you run your program with properly set path to sqljdbc_auth.dll. But if you export your application to .jar file and just run it, you will get these errors cause there is no correct classpath to auth file.

So, if you run your app from command line with proper arguments, it should be working.

Comment: It's a GUI project, meaning it's a jar-file supposed to be executed by a user by clicking it. So there's no way to add launching arguments, is there?